# Hangman "cannot read setAttribute of null" problem. How to get an element to exist in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

So I am making a hangman game using plain javascript. I have gotten to the point of checking the letters that correspond to the selected word. In the `checkLetter` function, I am trying to find if an element(letter) exists in the array or not and then update the array. With the specified element, the setAttribute will update the value or a new attribute will be added with the specified name and value. In the console logs, it says null and means that it does not exist yet. I dynamically created a button in the js but I don't know why it's not recognizing the setAttribute. I hope I am clear enough. Looking for some input, thanks.

```
window.onload = function() {

    const redoButton = document.getElementById("reset");
    const displayLetter = document.getElementById("answer-input");
    const placeLetters = document.getElementById("letter-input")
    const revealWord = document.getElementById("revealword");
    const healthBar = document.getElementById("lives");
    const keyboardBtn = document.getElementById("keyboard")


    //variables needed
    let lives = 8;
    let currentWord = [];
    let randomWord = '';//generates word from list
    let letterGuess = [];
    let lettersInWord;
    let emptySlots = 0;
    let alphabet = ["A", "B", 'C', 'D', "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];

    const words = [
        "Portland", "Berlin", "Boston", "Manchester",
        "Sevilla", "Madrid", "Medellin", "Houston",
        "Portland", "Miami", "Paris", "Cordoba"
    ]

    //keyboard added dynamically
    function createButtons() {
        for (let i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
            let buttons = document.createElement("button");
            buttons.innerHTML =
                `<button
            id = ${alphabet[i]}
            class="btn btn-primary"
            button type="button" 
            onClick = "checkLetter(this.id)"                                   
            >
            ${alphabet[i]}
            </button>`;

            keyboardBtn.appendChild(buttons)
        }
    }
    createButtons();


    //check letter of chosen word, if its there or not
//SETATTRIBUTE is where the error is coming from
    const checkLetter = function (id) {

        let click = document.getElementById(id);
        console.log(click);
        //console.log(id);

        for (let i = 0; i < emptySlots; i++) {
            //check if letter is in array
            if (currentWord.indexOf(id) === -1) {
                currentWord.push(id);//push letter into currentWord
            } else if (currentWord.indexOf(id) > -1) {
                return null //already exists in array
            }
        }
        document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("disabled", true)
        console.log(id)
    }
    checkLetter();


    //select random word from word array
    function chosenWord() {
        //choses random word from array
        randomWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
        console.log(randomWord);

        //letters split up in array
        lettersInWord = randomWord.split("");
        console.log(lettersInWord)

        emptySlots = lettersInWord.length;

        for (let i = 0; i < emptySlots; i++) {
            currentWord.push("-")
        }
        console.log(currentWord);
        placeLetters.innerHTML = currentWord.join(" ");

    }
    chosenWord()

}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">
    <title>Hangman 2021</title>
</head>

<body>

    <!--header-->
    <header class="container-fluid bg-success text-dark">
        <div>
            <span>
                <h1 class="text-center">Hang that man</h1>
            </span>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <br>
        <h3>Please choose a letter on your keyboard to reaveal the secret word</h3>
        <br>
        <!--each letter will display after all lives are gone-->
        <div id="keyboard"></div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <!--choices will be inserted here-->
        <div id="answer-input">
            <p id="letter-input">_</p>
        </div>

        <!--number of lives will be tracked here-->
        <p id="lives">You have 8 lives left</p>

        <!--everytime a guess is wrong, a limb is added to animation-->
        <section class="animation">
            <div class="justify-content-center">
                <canvas id="gallows" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3"></canvas>
            </div>
            <button id="reset">Play Again</button>
        </section>
        <br>
    </div>

    <!--footer-->
    <footer class="container-fluid bg-success text-dark">
        <div class="justify-content-center">Hang that man © 2021</div>
        <div class="social justify-content-center">
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/andres-ramirez12/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
            &nbsp;&#124;&nbsp;
            <a href="https://github.com/ARam2142" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="github">
            <a>Andres Ramirez</a>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You call `checkLetter();` without a parameter, but the entire function relies on it having an id.

Comment: Can you paste your html code?

Comment: So i will add it to the post